# cambiar el color de las cuadriculas en chart js React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

No se como Cambiar el color de las cuadriculas del grafico  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no se si chart js tenga una propiedad para editarlo

Agradezco de antemano

Comment: Necesitas proveer más información sobre el problema, por favor revisa las secciones de ayuda de la comunidad para saber cómo formular una buena pregunta.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que no pones ningún ejemplo de código supondremos que estás usando algo similar a lo siguiente:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("radar-chart"), {
    type: 'radar',
    data: {
      labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "Latin America", "North America"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "1950",
          fill: true,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(50,181,198,0.2)",
          borderColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
          pointBorderColor: "#fff",
          pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
          data: [8.77,55.61,21.69,6.62,6.82]
        }, {
          label: "2050",
          fill: true,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
          borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
          pointBorderColor: "#fff",
          pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
          pointBorderColor: "#fff",
          data: [25.48,54.16,7.61,8.06,4.45]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Distribution in % of world population'
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="radar-chart" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Si te das cuenta, en cada dataset puedes definir los colores tanto del borde como del background o incluso los puntos...

> Ejemplo sacado de https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/chartjs-charts-to-get-you-started/

Comment: Hola carlos muchas gracias por tu ayuda, con los colores y estilos del datasets tengo idea de como editarlos ,pero con lo que no tengo claridad es si puedo cambiar las lineas o cudriculas con que esta representado el grafico ,. osea la forma del grafico en si